# Spring MVC form:radiobuttons tag not setting value attribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, enums, radio-button

Here is relevant code from my controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("store_location_types")
public StoreLocationType[] getStoreLocationTypes() {
    return StoreLocationType.values();
}
```

Here is the definition of StoreLocationType, defined in the same controller:

```
private enum StoreLocationType {
    PHYSICAL("Physical"),
    ONLINE("Online");

    private String displayName;
    private String value;

    private StoreLocationType(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.value = this.name();
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Here is the the relevant JSP code:

```
        <li>
            <label>Location Type:</label>
            <form:radiobuttons path="StoreLocationType" items="${store_location_types}" itemLabel="displayName" itemValue="value"/>
        </li>
```

Here is what gets generated when the page is rendered:

```
    <li>
        <label>Location Type:</label>            
        <span>
            <input id="StoreLocationType1" name="StoreLocationType" type="radio" value="">                         
            <label for="StoreLocationType1">Physical</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="StoreLocationType2" name="StoreLocationType" type="radio" value="">       
            <label for="StoreLocationType2">Online</label>
        </span>
    </li>
```

The value attributes are not being populated with the "value" field of my enum.  What am I doing wrong here?  What I would expect to see is this:

```
        <span>
            <input id="StoreLocationType1" name="StoreLocationType" type="radio" value="PHYSICAL">                         
            <label for="StoreLocationType1">Physical</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="StoreLocationType2" name="StoreLocationType" type="radio" value="ONLINE">       
            <label for="StoreLocationType2">Online</label>
        </span>
```

The value attribute of the input tag should be the value of StorLocationType.ONLINE.getValue()

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find any problem in your code. When I tested it works well.

But in the case you can do it in a simpler way. You don't need to add the `value` field in the enum. If you omit the `itemValue` attribute of `<form:radiobuttons>` Spring will put the name of instances of enum for the value of `itemValue` attribute.

So you can do like this.

Enum

```
private enum StoreLocationType {
    PHYSICAL("Physical"),
    ONLINE("Online");

    private String displayName;

    private StoreLocationType(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}
```

JSP

```
<label>Location Type:</label>
<form:radiobuttons path="StoreLocationType" 
    items="${store_location_types}" itemLabel="displayName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using multiple radiobutton tags instead of a single radiobuttons tag.

Here is the code of the JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${store_location_types}">
    <form:radiobutton path="StoreLocationType" value="${item.value}"/>${item.displayName}
</c:forEach>
```

I used plain objects from database, so in my case value was the Id and the displayed string was the description. But this should work with enum too.